# Web Scraping in Excel VBA Code Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I need an Excel spreadsheet where I have a table that I can fill the "`Site where I want to collect data`", "`the code or product name I want to search`" and "t`he zip code where the product will be delivered`" and with that the table would copy from the site and paste in the spreadsheet the "`FREIGHT VALUE`".

I need to do this with retail sites like `Lojas Americanas`, `Magazine Luiza` or whatever site that have a freight value. I need the code to be editable in a way that I can use for any such site.

Is it possible?

I got halfway there with a code that I was able to assemble in VBA, I was able to make the code open Internet Explorer and enter the site I want in exactly the product I chose. But I could not make a code that can do the rest, which would put the zip code I want, do the freight search, copy the freight value and paste in the Excel spreadsheet.

Here's below (I haven't finished the code yet):

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ixu.png)

```
Sub lReferenciaIE()

Dim ObRef

On Error Resume Next

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 1, 1

End Sub

Sub lsSearchFreight()

lReferenciaIE

Dim ie                  As Object
Dim doc                 As HTMLDocument
Dim lNomProd            As String
Dim lCodProd            As String
Dim lCepProd            As String

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

url_name = Worksheets("Plan1").Range("E2")

If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub

    lCodProd = Range("A2").Value
    lNomProd = Range("B2").Text
    lCepProd = Range("C2").Value

    ie.Navigate (url_name) & "produto/" & lCodProd & "?pfm_carac=0&pfm_index=0&pfm_page=search&pfm_pos=grid&pfm_type=search_page%20&sellerId"

    While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend

    sng = Timer
    Do While sng + 5 > Timer
    Loop

    Set doc = ie.Document

    ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field").Value = lCepProd

    ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field-button").Click

MsgBox "Value OK!"

End Sub
```

Comment: What bit isn't working, the button clicking?

Comment: This both codes: (`ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field").Value = lCepProd` and `ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field-button").Click`). The first code were supposed to fill the search field of the zip code, and the second code would click the button that confirm the zip code to the site and bring the freight value.

Comment: But both aren't working

Comment: What does "aren't working" look like?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Debug where the error is, so assign variables, you can use `object` and `typename` to determine any types needed in future, but split `ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field").` into it's parts, so you can check and make sure `ie` is something then say `dim doc as object: set doc=ie.document` see if the document object can be obtained ok, then `dim ele as object: set ele=ie.Document.getElementById("freight-field")` see if you have the element and so on..

Comment: @TimWilliams When I said "`aren't working`", I want to say that I play the code, the Internet Explorer opens the site I want and in the product I want, but nothing happens in the page and in the Excel the messenge box "`Value OK!`" apperars.

Comment: Unless you have a finite list of website to consider (and for that list to be relatively short) you are unlikely to write anything robust I'm afraid. There is simply too much variability across websites.